# How to determine the version of cnosdb I am using?

Tags: cnosdb

I saw on the official website documentation that different versions of cnosdb have significant differences in configuration files and features. I want to determine the version of cnosdb I am using. I saw some version-related content in the cargo.toml file, but how can I determine the version of cnosdb I am using in the running binary?

- Syntax

```sql
select @@server_version
```

- returns

```
Server version information.
```

Comment: Is this directly outputted using database tools or just some DB adapter that reads first line of output?